# in unity, lightmap comes out blurry on android device

Tags: unity, android, lightmap

[image]

as you see, shadow is blurred. (see the tree's shadow)

What settings should I add?

Answer (score -3):

Mkj6026, I think you should polish the gameObject which stands for the TREE. Because, look at the car. The car's shadow isn't blurred. There is something wrong only with the trees. Try re-implementing your lighting. Or you can also try adding more trees to your scene and see if the problem still persists. If it does, try changing the code of your tree gameObject and check if something's wrong.

I think think your code is correct and there shouldn't be any problem. You can also try testing on another Google Android device.

Comment: I did not have enough explanation. Cars and characters use realtime lighting. All the rest are using lightmap. Anything that uses lightmap is blurry.

Comment: @mjk6026 Please add as many details as you can to your question so people can understand more about the problem.

Comment: @mjk6026 There is not a SINGLE line of code. How can you downvote my answer? Five details and then we'll talk about it.

Comment: Sorry to make you uncomfortable.

First, there is no need for code. This is an asset setting problem not related to code.

Second, the necessary explanation seems to have already been done.

Comment: Don't be too literal, buddy. What I meant is give DETAILS. You have given the final output of your project. Can't I even expect the editor view?

Comment: Yes. The left picture of the post is a screenshot of Unity's 'editor view'. The picture on the right shows the result of the samsung galaxy s4 device.

And the problem I am having is that the results of the shadows are different, as shown above.

The light settings are mixed and the trees are lightmap static. car is not.

These explanations are exactly what I wrote above. Ask for more explanation.